# Objective-C & ASIHTTPRequest return values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in an Objective-C Mac application. I am creating a class that accesses a web service's public API (via ASIHTTPRequest), let's call it `PublicAPI`. What I am wanting to do is write methods that directly return data from the web service, something like this...

```
publicAPI = [[PublicAPI alloc] initWithAccountInfo:email:[self email] password:[self password]];
NSArray *theData = [publicAPI getData];
```

So, `getData` needs to initiate the ASIHTTPRequest *AND* return the response from the server. The problem is that I want to make the ASIHTTPRequest calls with ASIHTTPRequest's `startAsynchronous` option, which delegates the server's response to a `requestFinished` method.

**How can I use the result of `requestFinished` as the return value of the `getData` method?**

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach would require that `getData` wait until the response came back before returning which would make the connection synchronous. This does not really make sense.

The delegate pattern that is already implemented by ASIHTTPRequest (and NSURLConnection for that matter) is the best approach here.

If you just need to make a synchronous connection for testing, NSURLConnection has a class method for that:

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, that makes sense. So, given that, what would the customary method of getting the data back again be? Perhaps the 'getData' would just initiate the request (and not return anything) and then I'd use NSNotification to tell the other classes that the data has returned? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a delegate with success / failure callbacks. If you need to inform many classes at once you can broadcast a notification. The cool way to do it would be with success / failure blocks. There is a recipe that wraps NSURLConnection with block callbacks in the great new iOS Recipes book (currently in beta): http://pragprog.com/titles/cdirec/ios-recipes

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The information you provided was excatly what I needed. This article helped too: http://css.dzone.com/articles/do-not-publishcreating-your

Answer (score 0):

Make your 
    [publicAPI getData] 
actually be a subclass of ASIHTTPRequest. That will receive the ASI delegate's callbacks (success,fail) and that will process (JSON, XML, CoreData, whatever) your incoming data.

You could use any type of notification, after the data is processed, to get the NSArray data back to where you want it.

If you subclass for each of your backend's API calls, with a common system of processing each for your API, you can make communicating with your backend nice and easy.